# C Scanf skipping in Xcode

Tags: c, scanf

new guy here.  I've been at this for a month or so (C to Obj C to Cocoa to iOS Apps progression)

Upon returning to some basic C, I am stumped with the apparently common "scanf skips the next scanf since it's eating the return keystroke" issue. I've tried adding #c to the second scanf, i've tried adding a space in there too, but it still skips the second scanf and I'm always returning 0 as my average.  I know there are better input commands than scanf.   But for now, there has to be a way to get something as simple as this to work?

Thanks! 
~Steve

```
int x;
int y;

printf("Enter first number:");
scanf("#i", &x);

printf("Enter second number:");
scanf("#i", &y);

printf("\nAverage of the two are %d", ((x+y)/2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `%d` format specifier to read `integer` input.

```
scanf("%d", &x); 
scanf("%d", &y);
```

And Print average by casting to float

```
printf("\nAverage of the two are %6.2f", ((float)(x+y)/2));
```

Test code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

int x;
int y;

printf("Enter first number:");
scanf("%d", &x);

printf("Enter second number:");
scanf("%d", &y);

printf("\nAverage of the two are %6.3f\n", ((float)(x+y)/3));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still skips the second and always returns an average of 0.

Comment: Gangadhar your code works.!  I understand the casting the final printf as a float, makes sense...  I hadnt even gotten there yet!

Comment: the crazy thing is, that i changed the i's to d's in my code and it still doesnt work, but when I paste dyour section of code in it does work.....?

Comment: is there anything else you changed?

Comment: and when I change the specifiers in your code to i, the code still works.

Answer (score 1):

When you hit enter key after entering first number the new line character left on stdin. Therefore, it takes new line character as next input(second number). You should leave a white space before %d in second scanf() function. scanf(" %d", &y);

```
int x;
int y;

printf("Enter first number:");
scanf("%d", &x);

printf("Enter second number:");
scanf(" %d", &y);

printf("\nAverage of the two are %d", ((x+y)/2));
```